# Calculate commutator with abstract sum using Cadabra

Tags: symbolic-math, symbolic-references

Is there a way of calculating the of abstract sums in Cadabra? E.g., is it possible to show that
`[a_i, sum_{j} a_j^\dagger a_j] = a_i`, where `[a_i, a_j^dagger] = delta_{ij}`?

I found a similar post here: [Sympy: How to get simplified commutators using the second quantization module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254012/sympy-how-to-get-simplified-commutators-using-the-second-quantization-module), but I couldn’t figure out how to do this for abstract sums...

If this is not possible with cadabra, can I do this with some other software?

Comment: Interesting question, but you might find a more receptive audience at math.stackexchange.com.